# Parsing "Key" = "Value" pair

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I'm trying to parse the string in the folowing format using the regex:

```
"Key" = "Value";
```

The following code is used to extract the "key" and "value":

```
NSString* pattern = @"([\"\"'])(?:(?=(\\\\?))\\2.)*?\\1";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
                                                                       options:0
                                                                         error:NULL];
NSRange matchRange = NSMakeRange(0, line.length);
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:line options:0 range:matchRange];
NSRange rangeKeyMatch = [match rangeAtIndex:0];

matchRange.location = rangeKeyMatch.length;
matchRange.length = line.length - rangeKeyMatch.length;
NSTextCheckingResult *match2 = [regex firstMatchInString:line options:0 range:matchRange];
NSRange rangeValueMatch = [match2 rangeAtIndex:0];
```

It doesn't look efficient and is not considering the following example as invalid:

```
"key" = "value" = "something else";
```

Is there any efficient way to perform parse of this kind of parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with that dialect, but since you've tagged `regex`, here's one that should do it in principle: `^"([^"]*)" = "([^"]*)";$`

You're not being exact about the format so you may need to add some conditional white-space here and there depending on your input format. Another thing that might come into play is the need to escape the parentheses.

For example with `sed`, you'd have to write:

`echo '"Key" = "Value";' | sed -e 's#^"\([^"]*\)" = "\([^"]*\)";$#key is \1 and value is \2#'`

Comment: NSRegularExpression follows [the ICU standard](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp), in case people are interested. Ah, and just to make the pattern slightly more robust, I'd use `\s+` in place of the single space.

Answer (score 1):

This code should match `"key" = "value"` and not `"key" = "value" = "something else"`:

```
NSString *line = @"\"key\" = \"value\"";

NSError *error = NULL;
NSString *pattern = @"\\\"(\\w+)\\\"\\s=\\s\\\"(\\w+)\\\"$";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines error:&error];
NSRange matchRange = NSMakeRange(0, line.length);
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:line options:0 range:matchRange];

/* It looks like you were not quite looking at the ranges properly. The rangeAtIndex 0 is actually the entire string. */
NSRange rangeKeyMatch = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
NSRange rangeValueMatch = [match rangeAtIndex:2];

NSLog(@"Key: %@, Value: %@", [line substringWithRange:rangeKeyMatch], [line substringWithRange:rangeValueMatch]);
```